# Copying files with specific name to respective directories

Tags: shell, unix

I have a source directory in UNIX hiving below files
20180401abc.txt,20180402acb.txt,20180402def.txt

and in target having directories like 20180401,20180402

How can i move 20180401abc.txt to 20180401 & 20180402acb.txt,20180402def.txt to 20180402 directories respectively.

using below code ,

```
ls /home/source/ > filelist.txt
for line in `cat filelist.txt`
do
dir_path=`echo $line|cut -c1-8`
mkdir -p "/home/target/${dir_path}"
find /home/source/ -type f -exec cp {} /home/target/${dir_path} \;
done
#rm filelist.txt
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but if you want to loop over all files in a directory you could just do e.g. `for file in /home/source/*; do ... done` No need for the temporary file containing the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use below script, it will solve your issue:-

```
 ls /home/source/ > filelist.txt

 while read filename
 do
     dir_name=$(echo $line | cut -c1-8 )
     dir_path="/home/target/"$dir_name
     mkdir $dir_path
     chmod 666 $dir_path
     mv $filename $dir_path
 done < filelist.txt
 rm -rf filelist.txt
```

Comment: Below code working for me::

for filename in `ls /home/source/`
do
dir_name=$(echo $filename | cut -c1-8)
dir_path="/home/target/${dir_name}"
mkdir -p $dir_path
cp /home/source/$filename $dir_path
done

Comment: @sidharthaswain, Is my solution fixed your issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ touch 20180401abc.txt 20180402acb.txt 20180402def.txt
$ for F in *.txt; do 
    DIR=$(echo $F | sed -r 's/[a-z]{3}.txt$//');
    mkdir -p $DIR; 
    mv $F $DIR/$F; 
  done

$ find                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
> ./20180402                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
> ./20180402/20180402acb.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                            
> ./20180402/20180402def.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                            
> ./20180401                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
> ./20180401/20180401abc.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Code listed below is working:

```
for filename in `ls /home/source/`
do
dir_name=$(echo $filename | cut -c1-8)
dir_path="/home/target/${dir_name}"
mkdir -p $dir_path
cp /home/source/$filename $dir_path
done
```